# Is it possible to dynamically create a sticker pack for iMessage through a companion app?

Tags: ios, imessage

I'm looking to create a Sticker Pack for iMessage, loaded with preset images but having the ability for users to create their own custom stickers. It seems like an iMessage app wouldn't be able to give users that choice, but would a standalone app be able to do that? Everything I see seems to be based on the assumption that the developer uploads a set of stickers to the store and that these cannot be edited in any way afterwards.

Another option would be to store the edited/exported stickers from the app to a server, and then access that from the iMessage app.

Does anyone know if one of these might be possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can create an iMessage app, either stand-alone or as an extension within an iOS app that has the ability to provide stickers dynamically. See https://developer.apple.com/imessage/ to get started.

Comment: @Paulw11 Awesome, thank you!